# SwiftUI Form not positioning correctly using Spacer()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, forms, swiftui

I am trying to create a profile page, in which there is a form at the bottom with various options. However when I insert a `Spacer(`) into the `VStack`, the form does not move to the bottom of the screen, as it should do. I tried replacing the Form with a Text and it worked fine, moving to the bottom of the screen. So I'm assuming it has something to do with the form.

[image: the current layout]

Here is my code

```
struct Profile: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
//                    .padding(.top)

                Text("email@email.com")
                    .font(.title)

                Spacer()

                Form {
                    Section {
                        //menuListItem(image: "gear", label: "Settings")
                        menuListItem(image: "questionmark.circle", label: "Help")                     menuListItem(image: "info.circle", label: "About")
                    }

                    Section {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "LoggedIn")
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "user_id")
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "school_id")
                                self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }) {
                                Text("Log Out")
                                    .font(.body)
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Profile", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct menuListItem: View {

    var image: String
    var label: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: image)
            Text(label)
                .font(.body)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as bottom of the Form is unknown(because Form is scrollable and its items start from the top), swiftUI does not know how much space should put between those two views. So `Spacer()` does not help.

Try this:

Give your form: for example, `.frame(height: 500)` or `.padding(.top, 400`) modifier.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. How is the bottom of a `Form` any different from the bottom of a `VStack` or `List`? It's unknown until it reaches the trailing "}" and then it knows. Why does a `List` or `VStack` move to the top, but not a 'Form'? using `.frame` or `.padding` is a hack, not a solution.