# Make SwiftUI Form wrap contents properly

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui

Swift 5.1
There's a `View` that contains a `Form`.  When I put that `View` in any other `View`, the `Form` takes up way more space than it needs.  For example:

```
VStack {
    Form {
        Text("Form")
    }
    Text("Not form")
    Text("Also not form")
}
```

This results in the entire screen being taken up by the `Form` (containing only the one `Text`), save for the two `Text` squashed way down at the bottom.  How do I get `Form` to shrink-wrap to the size of its contents?  `.frame(height: 100)` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59635380/513038) *vaguely* works, but you have to know how big the contents are, beforehand, which isn't always the case.

Comment: Yeah I have ran into a lot of issues with forms. The problem tends to happen because the form has a header that takes up a lot of space. I usually just do the hacky way and play around with the .frames (It is probably not the correct way but oh well)

Comment: Did you figure out a way to compress it?

Comment: @hyouuu Not as far as I remember; sorry